# how to view crashes that happen during development

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to view all the crashes that happened on my iOS device while I am building the app ? I've read that it is possible to retrieve crash logs for simulator but would it be possible also for the physical devices we test on ? I had a crash but then the screen went away and I didn't get a chance to see what exactly it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can retrieve crash logs from your devices in Xcode from "Devices and Simulators" in the Window menu. Just select the Devices tab and look for the "View Device Logs" button.

[image]

Do note that these are low-level crash reports and won't be as helpful as when you can actually catch the crash in an attached debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from this solutions there is one more approach to getting crash logs in other way.

As you are building an app, you install Fabric/Crashlytics, read the following link:

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

You have to follow their instructions and setup the SDK in your app.

By installing this you can able to track & repair the crashes on other iOS devices too. I hope this will be an alternative for you.

Comment: Does crashlytics report the same crashes as the developer consoles ?

Comment: A bit in different way.....but you will get the cause of crash with location of code...